VBA path changed and the current code steps over the new path
There was a data migration at the workplace, and the name of the network where all the files are stored changed, therefore the VBA Code had to be changed to the new path.
However when changed, the Code completely disregards the new path, and steps over it.
It was previously:
MyFiles = Dir("\\server_name\folder\folder\folder\folder\folder\folder\1*.xls")
    Do While MyFiles <> ""
        Workbooks.Open "\\server_name\folder\folder\folder\folder\folder\folder\" & MyFiles

And the current code is:
MyFiles = Dir("\\changed_server_name\changed_folder\folder\folder\folder\folder\folder\1*.xls")
    Do While MyFiles <> ""
        Workbooks.Open "\\changed_server_name\changed_folder\folder\folder\folder\folder\folder\" & MyFiles

Note that the first 2 segments of the path changed, and it makes the code completely nuts.
The Workbook that contains the code opens multiple workbooks, so that's why i can't use 'Activeworkbook.Path'

I'm 100% certain that it worked before the data migration, the only thing changed was the path of the files that need to be opened.

Ist the sting MyFiles always empty? Does the folder exist? Is the filter correct (file extension and filename starting with 1)?

MyFiles he names of the excel files that need to be opened and where we get the data from. It always changes, and the amount of excel files can change, but the MyFiles string is never empty. And yes, filter is correct, all files start with '1', file extension is .xls.
